# Promise.all cannot find Resolve for parent Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a page that contains N html selects. I have a function called 'run_all_ajax' that loops through them and calls an ajax function that populates them. I want a promise to return from run_all_ajax only when Promise.all completes within it.

Right now, the console reads;

all done, 0

after all done

0,1,2,3, etc

meaning that the promise.all is resolving before i have added to the promises array. How do I correct this?

Also, I want to understand how the array of promises works in terms of timing. Are we assuming that we can loop through the array of selects and add them to the array of promises faster than we could resolve all outstanding promises with the Promise.all()?

```
function run_all_ajax() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var promises = [];

        $("[selectgrid]").each(function (i, obj) {

            $.ajax({
                //stuff
                success: function (response) {
                    //stuff
                    console.log(i);
                }, //end: success

                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {//
                    promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { resolve("Complete"); }));
                }
            }); //end: $.ajax

        });

        Promise.all(promises).then(function (values) {
            console.log('all done, ' + promises.length);
            resolve("Complete");  
        });
    }); //end promise
}

run_all_ajax().then(function(){
    console.log('after all done');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `push` a promise at the wrong place (time). There is no need to create a `new Promise`. The promise you need is returned by `$.ajax()`.

So do:

```
promises.push($.ajax({
    //stuff
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

`promises.push` is called when a request is complete which is way after `Promise.all` is executed.

Basically you are calling `Promise.all([])` which resolves immediately.

This

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { resolve("Complete"); })
```

also resolves immediately. It's equal to `Promise.resolve("Complete")`